# Why is Rails unpermitting its own automatically set parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

My Login just broke.  It worked just fine up to now, but now I get: "unpermitted parameters".

```
Started POST "/login" for ::1 at 2017-09-30 20:29:47 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nDc9mpnsSvQSvHqACAgKteUi/ekfofao5sI9fe67iWaKikZul+mkKfRlkHtYiQtP71DrEmEZZtNnwlkXTvlNAg==", "username"=>"bjelline", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log In"}
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token, :commit
```

I did not set these paraemters utf8, authenticity_token and commit.  So I assume it's something rails did automatically.

Why is Rails unpermitting the parameters it set itself?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception   # this was missing
```

I removed "protect_from_forgery" by mistake.
This is the part of rails that automatically sets and checks the
authenticity_token.